# Mailx not reporting the IP the mail was sent from in header?

Tags: postfix, email-server, email

In the Header file of the final mail on y local server using postfix i am not able to see the Sender's ip which is usually under received from.

```
From root@testmailer.com  Wed May 28 12:26:54 2014
Return-Path: <root@testmailer.com>
X-Original-To: kharekartik@testmailer.com
Delivered-To: kharekartik@testmailer.com
Received: by testmailer.com (Postfix, from userid 0)
        id A503876209C; Wed, 28 May 2014 12:26:54 +0530 (IST)
Subject: test
To: <kharekartik@testmailer.com>
Cc: <kharekartik@virtualmailer.com>
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.2)
Message-Id: <20140528065654.A503876209C@testmailer.com>
Date: Wed, 28 May 2014 12:26:54 +0530 (IST)
From: root@testmailer.com (root)
```

here's the configuration of mailing server:

```
myorigin = $myhostname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = testmailer.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = tcmailer8.in, karan-desktop, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks =192.168.1.13 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/

#sender dependent ip
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/dependent
#smtp_bind_address = 192.168.1.13

#virtual mailbox setup
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
```

Comment: Do you have `header_checks` enabled? Show config of your sending server.

Comment: When email was delivered LOCALLY, it doesn't print any IP address because there are no smtp transaction

Answer (score 1):

When email was submitted by `mail` command (or `sendmail` binary) and delivered LOCALLY, it doesn't print any IP address because there are no smtp transaction. Here's the email flow

> Pickup -> Qmgr -> smtp (relay via local)

Proof from maillog

```
Oct 12 08:09:51 web postfix/pickup[48333]: 865E134781F: uid=1010 from=<masegaloeh>
Oct 12 08:09:51 web postfix/cleanup[48757]: 865E134781F: message-id=<20141012010951.865E134781F@example.com>
Oct 12 08:09:51 web postfix/qmgr[79683]: 865E134781F: from=<masegaloeh@example.com>, size=327, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 12 08:09:51 web postfix/smtp[48759]: 865E134781F: to=<root@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.21, delays=0.01/0.17/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
```

As you can see, there are no TCP connection at all. Postfix just passing email between its minion programs.